# Replacement of "placeholder" in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a ML beginner and have a basic understanding of TF. I am converting a code based on TF1 which uses the now deprecated tf.placeholder to a TF2 compatible code (not using tf.compat.v1).

I want to rewrite this snippet:

```
class MyNeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, x, t):
        ...
        self.x = x
        self.t = t

        self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                                     log_device_placement=True))

        self.x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x.shape[1]])
        self.t_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t.shape[1]])

        self.f_pred = self.net_f(self.x_tf)

        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_pred))

        self.optimizer_Adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        self.train_op_Adam = self.optimizer_Adam.minimize(self.loss)

    def net_f(self, x, t):
        u = self.MyNet(x,t)    # MyNet defines custom layers (not shown here)
        f = tf.gradients(u, t)[0]
        return f

    def train(self, nIter):
        tf_dict = {self.x_tf: self.x, self.t_tf: self.t}
        self.sess.run(self.train_op_Adam, tf_dict)
```

(I have kept only the relevant snippets from the parent code: https://github.com/maziarraissi/PINNs/blob/master/appendix/continuous_time_identification%20(Burgers)/Burgers.py)

In this code, it is possible to use a dictionary tf_dict to pass the tensors defined as tf.placeholder. In TF2, I would need to define loss and train_op_Adam differently. How can I do that ? Should I define them as functions and pass the arguments ?

I understand that this is could be a classical issue of migrating a code written in TF1 to TF2. I could not make it work by using the examples in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate.

Comment: Duplicate of [Replacing placeholder for tensorflow v2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58986126/1782792)? Essentially, yes, what you do in `__init__` should be done in a different method (or `__call__` if you prefer that) that is called on each training iteration, passing one batch at a time. If you use Keras, you will have some facilities for training and other things.