# What can replace tensorflow.placeholder()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I used to use tf.placeholder for writing variables that could be changed by session. Now I'm writing in Google Colaboratory and getting use to new Tensorflow_2.0 version. So I have problem with writing variable that could be change. With what can I replace this code in new version?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name='x')
```

Comment: this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986126/replacing-placeholder-for-tensorflow-v2

Comment: Change from `placeholder` to `keras.Input`

Comment: when i change to keras.Input i got error  `TypeError: Input() got multiple values for argument 'shape'`

Comment: `keras.Input(shape=(None, n_inputs))`