# ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs for dynamically constructed graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the same requirements as in [Replacing placeholder for tensorflow v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986126/replacing-placeholder-for-tensorflow-v2). I took the code refactored for Tensorflow 2 from @AlexisBRENON (not the one in compatibility mode) and ran it verbatim.
I get an error `ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs` pointing to the `multiply` part of this snippet:

```
make_dict[outg[0]] = tf.keras.layers.add([
    make_dict[outg[0]],
    tf.keras.layers.multiply(
        [[outg[1]], make_dict[queue[0]]],
    )],
)
```

What could have gone wrong there? Did the API change since then?

I tried wrapping `[[outg[1]], make_dict[queue[0]]]` into `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` because it is the closest thing I could find to a merge layer. It resulted in another error `ValueError: A Concatenate layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs`, even though it looks like there are two items in the list.

I am using Tensorflow 2.4.1

Comment: Did you get a solution, I am also stuck with the same error.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, and I cannot comment in the original question because of lack of reputation. I wish I could link my question there. I tried to provide a bit more information about the error here.

Comment: I already did and shared a colab (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZmM_SMftYbn0lQP0uJhXOZR2l1Ly0VhP?usp=sharing) that reproduces the error, I hope the author would check that out. Meanwhile, I think it's the change of the tf2 multiply API.

Comment: Ok, I resolved it and posted the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986126/replacing-placeholder-for-tensorflow-v2) work we need to make the following changes.
[multiply](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Multiply) is designed in tensorflow version `2.4.1` to only receive tensors as inputs within a list. Therefore, we need to change the constant weights of the computation graph to valid tensors. I am not sure how it was working in the original answer, here is the working example now.

The only real change is `outg[1]` to `K.constant([outg[1]])`

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

def construct_graph(graph_dict, inputs, outputs):
    queue = inputs[:]
    make_dict = {}
    for key, val in graph_dict.items():
        if key in inputs:
            # Use keras.Input instead of placeholders
            make_dict[key] = tf.keras.Input(name=key, shape=(), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
        else:
            make_dict[key] = None
    # Breadth-First search of graph starting from inputs
    print(make_dict)
    while len(queue) != 0:
        cur = graph_dict[queue[0]]
        for outg in cur["outgoing"]:
            #print(outg)
            if make_dict[outg[0]] is not None: # If discovered node, do add/multiply operation
                #print(type(make_dict[outg[0]]))
                print(outg[1])
                make_dict[outg[0]] = tf.keras.layers.add([
                    make_dict[outg[0]],
                    tf.keras.layers.multiply(
                        [ K.constant([outg[1]]), make_dict[ queue[0] ]  ]
                    )],
                )
            else: # If undiscovered node, input is just coming in multiplied and add outgoing to queue
                make_dict[outg[0]] = tf.keras.layers.multiply(
                    [make_dict[queue[0]], K.constant([outg[1]]) ]
                )
                for outgo in graph_dict[outg[0]]["outgoing"]:
                    queue.append(outgo[0])
        queue.pop(0)
    # Returns one data graph for each output
    model_inputs = [make_dict[key] for key in inputs]
    model_outputs = [make_dict[key] for key in outputs]
    return [tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_inputs, outputs=o) for o in model_outputs]

def make_graph():
    graph_def = {
        "B": {
            "incoming": [],
            "outgoing": [("A", 1.0)]
        },
        "C": {
            "incoming": [],
            "outgoing": [("A", 1.0)]
        },
        "A": {
            "incoming": [("B", 2.0), ("C", -1.0)],
            "outgoing": [("D", 3.0)]
        },
        "D": {
            "incoming": [("A", 2.0)],
            "outgoing": []
        }
    }
    outputs = construct_graph(graph_def, ["B", "C"], ["A"])
    print("Builded models:", outputs)
    for o in outputs:
        o.summary(120)
        print("Output:", o((1.0, 1.0)))


make_graph()
```

Gives the output

```
Model: "model"
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                           Output Shape               Param #       Connected to                            
========================================================================================================================
B (InputLayer)                         [(None,)]                  0                                                     
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
C (InputLayer)                         [(None,)]                  0                                                     
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_33 (Multiply)                 (None,)                    0             B[0][0]                                 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_34 (Multiply)                 (None,)                    0             C[0][0]                                 
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                              (None,)                    0             multiply_33[0][0]                       
                                                                                multiply_34[0][0]                       
========================================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Output: tf.Tensor([2.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: The error message is reallly misleading for that kind of exception

Comment: agreed, tensorflow is a messy place.